Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\left(\frac{-|x-X_i|^2}{2(\sigma/n)^2}\right)$
Let $X_1,...,X_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mu$ where has a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$: $\mu(dx)=\rho(x)dx$. For every $x$ show$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\left(\frac{-|x-X_i|^2}{2(\sigma/n)^2}\right)=\rho(x)\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}.
$$
I am very confident the result is true as it has been empirically verified. I arrived at this conjecture because of the following formal argument:\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \exp\left(\frac{-|x-X_i|^2}{2(\sigma/n)^2}\right)&\approx n \int\exp\left(\frac{-|x-y|^2}{2(\sigma/n)^2}\right)\rho(y)dy\\
&=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\left[\int\frac{n}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-|y|^2}{2(\sigma/n)^2}\right)\rho(x+y)dy\right]\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\int\delta(y)\rho(x+y)dy=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\rho(x)
\end{align}
where I have used the law of large numbers (this is really the part where I am not being precise), the weak convergence of the gaussian to the Dirac delta, and finally the definition of the Dirac delta.

Why is this argument not enough for you ?

because it is a heuristic

This is an interesting result - does it come from your research or some problem set?

It is from my research. I will be happy to share a preprint when its ready:) just pm me!

Thanks to some helpful suggestions, I was able to find a solution. For simplicity, I will prove it for the case of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and when $\rho$ is a K-Lipschitz continuous density. Define the function$$
\phi_n(x):=\exp\left(\frac{-|x|^2}{2\sigma^2 n^{-2/d}}\right)
$$ and notice $$
|n\phi_n*\rho(x)-(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\rho(x)|\leq\frac{C_1}{n^{1/d}}.
$$Indeed since $\int \phi_n(y)dy=n^{-1}(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}$, one has\begin{align*}|n\phi_n*\rho(x)-(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\rho(x)|&=n\left|\int \phi_n(y)[\rho(x-y)-\rho(x)]dy\right|\\
&=\left|\int \exp\left(\frac{-|y|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)[\rho(x-n^{-1/d}y)-\rho(x)]dy\right|\\
&\leq \int\exp\left(\frac{-|y|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)|\rho(x-n^{-1/d}y)-\rho(x)|dy\\
&\leq \frac{K}{n^{1/d}}\int|y|\exp\left(\frac{-|y|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)dy\\
&=\frac{K}{n^{1/d}}\cdot (2\pi)^{d/2}\sigma^{d}\cdot \sigma\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}=:\frac{C_1}{n^{1/d}}
\end{align*}
Define iid random variables $Z_1,...,Z_n$ by setting each $Z_i=\phi_n(x-X_i)$ and thus $\mathbb{E}[Z_i]=\phi_n*\rho(x)$. Furthermore, since each $Z_i\in(0,1)$ one has $\mathbb{E}[Z_i^k]\leq \mathbb{E}[Z_i]$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ therby establishing $\mathbb{E}[e^{Z_i}]\leq e\mathbb{E}[Z_i]$. Therefore,\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i-n\mathbb{E}[Z_1]>\varepsilon\right)&\leq e^{-(\varepsilon+n\mathbb{E}[Z_1])}\mathbb{E}\big[e^{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}\big]\\
&=e^{-(\varepsilon+n\mathbb{E}[Z_1])}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[e^{Z_i}]\\
&\leq e^{-(\varepsilon+n\mathbb{E}[Z_1])} e^n \mathbb{E}[Z_1]^n.
\end{align*}
Now, by the fact that $n\mathbb{E}[Z_1]=n\phi_n*\rho(x)\geq (2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\rho(x)-C_1/n^{1/d},$ one has $$
e^{-(\varepsilon+n\mathbb{E}[Z_1])}e^n\leq e^{-\varepsilon-(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\rho(x)}e^{n-C_1n^{-1/d}},
$$
and since $\rho\in L^1$ is continuous we have $\|\rho\|_\infty<\infty$, thus $\mathbb{E}[Z_1]\leq n^{-1}(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\|\rho\|_\infty=:C_2n^{-1}.$ Putting these estimates together, we see that$$
e^{-(\varepsilon+n\mathbb{E}[Z_1])} e^n \mathbb{E}[Z_1]^n\leq e^{-\varepsilon-(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\rho(x)}\frac{e^{n(\log(C_2)+1)-C_1n^{-1/d}}}{n^n}.
$$A similar argument can be applied to bound$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i-n\mathbb{E}[Z_1]<-\varepsilon\right).
$$Therefore, by the ratio test we see$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(\bigg|\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i-n\mathbb{E}[Z_1]\bigg|>\varepsilon\right)<\infty,
$$so by Borel-Cantelli, we have that$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \phi_n(x-X_i) -n\phi_n*\rho(x)\right|=0 
$$almost surely. Thus for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n_\varepsilon$ such that\begin{align*}
\Big|\sum_{i=1}^{n_\varepsilon}  \phi_{n_\varepsilon}(x-X_i) -(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\rho(x)\Big|&\leq \Big|\sum_{i=1}^{n_\varepsilon} \phi_{n_\varepsilon}(x-X_i)-n_\varepsilon\phi_{n_\varepsilon}*\rho(x)\Big|+\big|n_\varepsilon\phi_{n_\varepsilon}*\rho(x)-(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}\rho(x)\big|\\
&\leq \varepsilon+C_1n_\varepsilon^{-1/d}
\end{align*}
almost surely; letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ establishes the desired result.

What an incredible result, this surely must be recognized in a prestigious journal for machine learning!

please state where the error is, since you refer to an error in a followup question

I have not spotted the error, yet it seems strange that my concentration inequalities work for $\varepsilon=0$
